# Jquery click event not working after change event

Tags: html, jquery, dom

Here is my code:

```
 function change() {
        console.log("change");
        $('span[data-valmsg-for="Car"]').text('');
    }

$("#saveCar").on("click", function () {
            console.log("savecar");
            if (IsCarFormValid() == true) {
                $("#saveCar").attr("disabled", true);
                var model = {};

            }
        });
```

When I change data in input and click on button the button click event doesn't work. Why?

Comment: Can you create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/358993/1823841) here to show the issue happening.

Comment: Here is the example : https://jsfiddle.net/u5md1zk2/

Comment: Change text and click to save

Comment: Your save button still works

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen it's not working when you click on save button when input is active.

Comment: In your fiddle:  change the text, then "click" on the save button - save button doesn't "work".  That's because:  change the text,  mouse down on save (first part of click) - blur event fires, removes the validate message so the **save button moves**, mouse up is not on the save button - so you don't get a click event because you moved the button before click could fire.

Comment: @freedomn-m what you suggest to do?

Comment: First I recommend you never move your save button (so user always know where to click).  So you could 1) put the save button on the next line so that it doesn't move 2) put the validation message on the *right* of the button (I recommend this one if you don't want to reorder your layout) https://jsfiddle.net/kb75a3su/.

Comment: Or, if you must keep this layout, using `input` instead of `change` so the button moves before you try to click it.

Answer (score 1):

Using an `alert()` and you will see that the event is working fine:

```js
$("#Car").on("change", function() {
  console.log("vincode change");
  $('span[data-valmsg-for="Car"]').text('');
});

$("#saveCar").on("click", function() {
  alert("button is clicked")
  console.log("savecar");
  var model = {};
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" class="form-control" id="Car" name="Car" value="ggdsgdsagdgag">
<span data-valmsg-for="Car" class="text-danger">some validation error</span>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="saveCar">Save</button>
```

What can be a little confusing is that the sentence `some validation error` is deleted after an `onBlur` event (when the mouse click outside of the input). So if you change your text and click directly on the button, the text will first disappear that make that your cursor is no more on the button. So in practice, you don't click on the button.

But if you change the sentence, click outside of the input (not on the button) and **then** on the button, you will see the alert message.

Comment: It's not working in only one case. Click on save button after make changes on input, when text in span is exist.

Comment: @aniogs read the text after the first line that says "it's working fine" (when it's not)

Comment: Yes it's because of the `blur` event here. I explain it at the end of my post. So here it's not working but I figure out why. The question is `Why it's not working`?

Comment: @freedomn-m I said `the event is working fine` and it's the case. Problem don't come from the event itself but how it is triggered